# org-mode table header formatting not properly aligned

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a problem with table formatting in org-mode. I use Monospace font, fixed-pitch font face, but it still skewed as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

`C-u C-x =` shows:

```
             position: 358 of 23068 (2%), column: 26
            character: - (displayed as -) (codepoint 45, #o55, #x2d)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x2D
               script: latin
               syntax: _    which means: symbol
             category: .:Base, >:Not at bol, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 2d" or "C-x 8 RET HYPHEN-MINUS"
          buffer code: #x2D
            file code: #x2D (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x10)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: HYPHEN-MINUS
  general-category: Pd (Punctuation, Dash)
  decomposition: (45) ('-')

There are text properties here:
  face                 org-table
  fontified            t
```

Running `describe-face` for `org-table` face reports:

```
Face: org-table (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
Face used for tables.

Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.

           Family: unspecified
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: unspecified
           Weight: unspecified
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: #859900
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
          Inherit: fixed-pitch
```

fixed-pitch face is:

```
Face: fixed-pitch (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
The basic fixed-pitch face.

Defined in ‘faces.el’.

           Family: Monospace
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: unspecified
           Weight: unspecified
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: unspecified
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
          Inherit: unspecified
```

In other words, everything looks correct, but yet my table heading is askew.

Emacs 25.2.2 on Lunux. Org-mode 9.2.2.

Comment: What does the `fixed-pitch` face config look like?  `org-table` face is essentially the same as it because of the `:inherit`.

Comment: @jpkotta I've added fixed-pitch face summary to the question above.

Comment: OK, nothing looks weird there.  Is the the rest of the table also in `org-table` face?  I just made a table in org and it seems like all of it is `org-table` face.  Other than that, I'm not really sure what to check.  Maybe the font is weird. 
 Maybe also try `fc-match Monospace` from the shell.

Comment: I guess that `xft:` line from `describe-char` says it's DejaVu Sans Mono, which is what I use for my `default` face.  My hyphens are the same size as everything else.

Comment: @jpkotta one thing I noticed that when I put the cursor before "IdOp" on the first row below it highlights all empty space as a single character, while above it is shown as 2 dashes. Maybe it is something to do with tabs/indentation? Char properties show a single psace in monospace font. The only thing suspect is `display  (space :width 1) fontified  t`

Comment: yes, I can confirm that other spaces in the row are narrower. When checking their properties the difference is "display (space :width 1)" property. Now the question is how to fix this :)

Comment: ok, I figured it out. The problem shows when I change display size with C-x C--. Somehow initial column spaces with ":width 1" attribute remember old size and show larger. Trying to set "(setq org-table-separator-space " ")" in org-mode hook helps but when reopening document its effect is lost. It looks like a bug.

Comment: Somebody suggested that  `(setq org-table-separator-space (propertize " " 'display '(space :relative-width 1)))` is a better workaround